# Is there any method to calculate surface tension of packing of particles under external potential

Tags: simulations, surface-tension, molecular-dynamics, soft-matter

I want to calculate surface tension of stacking of particle which the surface is under a repulsive potential. The repulsive potential applying the force to the particles to have a surface (or interface) facing towards the direction which potential is applied to. The potential is dependent on the distance from the wall which is curved and the wall confines the particles.

Given the coordinates of N particles, their interactions among them, and the wall-particle potential which can be calculated from distance from the wall and the potential function, Can it be possible to obatin surface tension?.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand, could you write this maybe in equations and/or draw a figure? You're not referring to something like Pickering emulsions, right?

Comment: @alarge maybe you can refer to a system like this, [link](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmat4072)

Comment: In the link, you can see an assembly of spheres, and they are under confining potential (wall-particle potential; though the authors have tried other forms of confinement). So my question is how one can quantitatively calculate "effective" surface tension from the power of wall-particle potential.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand this, you have a bunch of hard spheres, and they are being squeezed together by a spherical potential. Hard spheres themselves don't make systems that have a surface tension: there are no attractions, and so, no cohesive force. So you'd really need to consider the spheres + wall system as a whole to make a surface. If you go through the math, I think what you'll end up is something like Young-Laplace equation, and all that remains to be determined is the pressure. 1/2

Comment: The pressure may be even known for hard spheres, but in case you're worried the exact details of the wall interaction might affect the final result significantly, you could go with the Buff-like quasithermodynamical route, and numerically compute and then integrate over the pressure tensor (and I guess for a bit more rigour you'll need to think where the surface is as obviously that will affect the result, but this is a much broader topic than what I could write in a short comment). 2/2

Comment: @alarge Thank you for the comment. Actually, I'm not using hard spheres (only repulsive potential) but I think that doesn't mean that I cannot use the approach you mentioned. Is there any good literature for understanding such a rigorous mathematical formalism?

Comment: Rowlinson & Widom's _Molecular Theory of Capillarity_ outlines many methods, including the one I talked about. That said, I should mention that this is not without some controversy and there is no clear consensus on whether one can even define, meaningfully, a local pressure/stress tensor from MD (it is used a lot in some fields, but that doesn't make it theoretically sound). My intuition would say that it should be fine, and that's essentially what you do in general relativity too, and all that is missing is some reconciliation of boundary conditions (which is something that many have tried).